# Filter an Array with fill and Map

Tags: javascript

I don't want to add a value 0 to the array as Object. It is getting mapped with newArray now. How can I fix that?

modus = `{start: -1, end: 0}`

Output newArray: `0: {value: -1, label: -1} 1: {value: 0, label: 0}`
Output newArray should be without the {value: 0, label: 0}

```
  const getOptions = (modus) => {
    console.log(modus.range.end + ' ' + modus.range.start)
    let data;
    if (modus.range.end < 0.00 ) {
    data = Array(modus.range.start - modus.range.end + 1).fill('').map((_, idx) => modus.range.end + idx)
    } else {
       data = Array(modus.range.end - modus.range.start + 1).fill('').map((_, idx) => modus.range.start + idx)
    }
    const newArray = data.map(item => ( { value: item, label: item } ));
      return newArray
  }
```

Comment: do you have ranges like -3, 3?

Comment: do you have some more examples?

Comment: I do have ranges from -3, 3 yes.

Comment: and what is with zero in this case?

Comment: The description of the desired results is very unclear. Do you mean you don't want to include the "end" (i.e. an exclusive range), or you never want "0" to appear as a label/value, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

You could omit zero values.

```js
const
    getObject = item => ({ value: item, label: item }),
    getOptions = ({ range: { start, end } }) => {
        [start, end] = [Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end)];
        const hasZero = start <= 0 && end >= 0;

        console.log(start, end, hasZero);
        return Array.from(
            { length: end - start + !hasZero },
            _ => getObject(start++ || start++)
        );
    }

console.log(getOptions({ range: { start: 0, end: -1 } }));
console.log(getOptions({ range: { start: -1, end: 0 } }));
console.log(getOptions({ range: { start: -3, end: 3 } }));
console.log(getOptions({ range: { start: 2, end: 5 } }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```